# Python : How would I consecutively add a number that increases by 10 every for loop cycle?

Tags: python

On every even birthday a girl, named Lily, receives as a present $10.00. Every next even birthday she receives $10 more than the previous one (so on her 2nd birthday she gets 10, on her 4th she gets 20, 6th she gets 30 and etc.) This is the for loop:

```
age = int(input())
saved_birthday_money = 0
for i in range(1, age + 1):
   if i % 2 == 0:
```

How would you code the rest of this problem (adding 10, then 20, then 30?)

Comment: what is your proposal ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a variable that starts at ten then has ten added to it each cycle. This ever-increasing amount is what gets added to her savings. The following pseudo-code should hopefully illustrate this:

```
set savings to zero
set gift to zero
for each alternate birthday:
    add ten to gift
    add gift to savings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of iterations but:

```
Money = 0
Gift = 0
for X in range(100):
    #She starts getting money at 2
    X += 2
    if X % 2 == 0:
        Gift += 10
        Money += Gift
print(Money)
```

This will plus 10 at the age of two, 20 at the age of 4 and so on